# Adding IP6 link local address to gretap interface

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, tunneling

I've created a GRETAP interface which is working:

```
$ ip link show t104016114 
15: t104016114@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1242 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:ef:75:cf:2c:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
$ ip address list t104016114
15: t104016114@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1242 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:ef:75:cf:2c:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.40.16.226/14 brd 10.43.255.255 scope global dynamic t104016114
       valid_lft 2836sec preferred_lft 2836sec
```

I'd like it to have an IP6 link-local address but this is where I get stuck:

```
$ ipv6calc --in prefix+mac fe80:: 06:ef:75:cf:2c:b6
No action type specified, try autodetection...found type: prefixmac2ipv6
fe80::4ef:75ff:fecf:2cb6
$ sudo ip addr add dev t104016114 scope link noprefixroute fe80::4ef:75ff:fecf:2cb6/64
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Can someone point out what exactly is invalid here?  Is there some way to get more information?

Comment: What is strange here, is that this ipv6 address should have been added automatically by the kernel as soon as the interface was brought up. Do you actually have ipv6 support? For example is the lo interface having the ::1 address when up?

Comment: I definitely have IP6 enabled - all the other interfaces have IP6 addresses.  I believe it is the expected behaviour for the kernel not to add IP6 addresses to tunnel interfaces automatically.

Comment: I've just tried this again, definitely gives the result above.  I'm running Ubuntu's 5.3.0-24-generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [RFC 2460](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460#section-5):

> 5. Packet Size Issues
>
>    IPv6 requires that every link in the internet have an **MTU of 1280**
>    octets or greater.  On any link that cannot convey a 1280-octet
>    packet in one piece, link-specific fragmentation and reassembly must
>    be provided at a layer below IPv6.

For some reason probably related to the tunneling (or multiple layers of tunneling) you're intending to do, your interface MTU is lower than 1280. In such case, the Linux implementation will not consider the interface eligible for IPv6. IPv6 gets disabled on it, as could show my tests:

```
# ip netns add testbed
```

Term1:

```
# ip -n testbed monitor
```

Term2:

```
# ip -n testbed link add t104016114 address 06:ef:75:cf:2c:b6 type gretap remote 10.100.0.2 local 10.100.0.1
```

Term1:

```
    inet t104016114 forwarding on rp_filter strict mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet6 t104016114 forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
5: t104016114@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 06:ef:75:cf:2c:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: t104016114@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 06:ef:75:cf:2c:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Note that by default the selected MTU is 1462.

Term2:

```
# ip -n testbed link set t104016114 up
```

Term1:

```
ff00::/8 dev t104016114 table local metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev t104016114 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
5: t104016114    inet6 fe80::4ef:75ff:fecf:2cb6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
local fe80::4ef:75ff:fecf:2cb6 dev t104016114 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
```

Term2:

```
# ip -n testbed link set t104016114 mtu 1242
```

Term1:

```
5: t104016114@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1242 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether 06:ef:75:cf:2c:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Deleted fe80::/64 dev t104016114 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
Deleted local fe80::4ef:75ff:fecf:2cb6 dev t104016114 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
Deleted ff00::/8 dev t104016114 table local metric 256 pref medium
Deleted ff02::2 dev t104016114 lladdr 33:33:00:00:00:02 NOARP
Deleted ff02::1:ffcf:2cb6 dev t104016114 lladdr 33:33:ff:cf:2c:b6 NOARP
Deleted ff02::16 dev t104016114 lladdr 33:33:00:00:00:16 NOARP
Deleted 5: t104016114    inet6 fe80::4ef:75ff:fecf:2cb6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
Deleted inet6 t104016114
```

Term2:

```
# ip -n testbed addr add dev t104016114 scope link noprefixroute fe80::4ef:75ff:fecf:2cb6/64
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Term2:

```
# ip -n testbed link set t104016114 mtu 1462
```

Term1:

```
5: t104016114@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1462 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether 06:ef:75:cf:2c:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 t104016114 forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
ff00::/8 dev t104016114 table local metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev t104016114 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
5: t104016114    inet6 fe80::4ef:75ff:fecf:2cb6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
local fe80::4ef:75ff:fecf:2cb6 dev t104016114 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref mediump-sysctl.txt?h=v5.3#n1739
```

For the minimum value, as expected, choosing 1279 will disable again IPv6, using mtu 1280 will allow back IPv6.

Comment: Yep, good spot.  The VPN the tunnel was carried over had a default MTU of 1280 so the tunnel ended up with a smaller MTU.

Comment: @Tom you can check my SF answer involving gretap for solution: [Wireguard as VM bridge without hypervisor visible on VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/982403/wireguard-as-vm-bridge-without-hypervisor-visible-on-vpn/984227#984227).  there are (quite messy) workarounds to fragment packets with a bigger MTU. I hope you can integrate this in your problem if needed.

Comment: It seems my VPN is tolerant of MTUs up to about 1450 without packet loss.  It just sets 1280 as a default for whatever reason.  Thanks again.